# MySQL JSON - SELECT WHERE

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I'm trying to `SELECT` objects base on the `roles` property values.

**Example:** Select all `names` where role is `1` //response would return `danny`

**Query Statement:**

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(username,'$[*].name') FROM objects WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(username,'1','$[*].roles')
```

**COLUMN: username (JSON)**

```
[
    {
        "name":"jordan",
        "roles":[1,2,5]
    },
    {
        "name":"danny",
        "roles":[1,4]
    }
]
```

**Question:** Why isn't my statement returning just the first object containing the name `danny`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM objects 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(components, '1', '$.roles');
```

Comment: It needs a `WHERE` clause

Comment: Yes, you have to add the condition in where clause only

Comment: It's not returning anything, this is an update so far `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(components,'$[*].elements') FROM objects WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(components,'1','$.roles');`

Comment: The statement is saying `SELECT` all `components->elements` FROM objects (table) WHERE the property `role` equals `1`

Comment: @xsami yeah very close! the problem I'm testing now is that it can't do multiple. example - `JSON_CONTAINS(components, '1,2', '$.roles');` or `JSON_CONTAINS(components, JSON_ARRAY(1,2) , '$.roles');` the return on multiple like `1,2` is strict and has to be in order unlike a `IN()` statement which would test each element of the array separately not linear.